# How to choose the dependencies names when sharing a JavaScript AMD module?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, dependencies, naming, amd

I'm writing a tool that depends on [HumanizeDuration.js](https://github.com/EvanHahn/HumanizeDuration.js) (could be any other dependency). Using RequireJS, in `main.js`:

```js
require.config({
  paths: {
    "humanizeDuration": "./path/to/humanize-duration" /* .js */,
    "myTool": "./path/to/my-tool" /* .js */
  }
  // ...
});
```

In `my-tool.js`:

```js
define(["humanizeDuration"], function (humanizeDuration) {
  // ...
}});
```

---

I would like to share my tool (e.g. on GitHub):

```js
(function (global, factory) {

  if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    define(["humanizeDuration"], factory);
  } else if (typeof exports === "object") {
    module.exports = factory(require("humanizeDuration"));
  } else {
    global.MyTool = factory(global.humanizeDuration);
  }

}(this, function (humanizeDuration) {
  // ...
}));
```

The question is: which name shall I choose for the dependency? Since it depends on how developers configured their `main.js` (for RequireJS), am I wrong?

Here, I chose `humanizeDuration`, so I could tell developers to use this name, but what if they use another tool that chose `humanize-duration` for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know there is a most commonly used name to refer to `HumanizeDuration.js` as an AMD module, use that, but you can use `humanizeDuration` if there is no common name or if you cannot determine one. Make sure to **document it** so that users know what to expect. Then if there is a problem because your tool wants `humanizeDuration` but another tool wants `humanize-duration`, the users of your tool can use [`map`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-map):

```
map: {
  '*': {
      "humanize-duration": "humanizeDuration"
  }
}
```

This tells RequireJS that everywhere (`'*'`) `humanize-duration` is required, load the module `humanizeDuration` instead. Obviously, in this case `humanizeDuration` is what is in the `paths`. The whole thing could be mapped in reverse if `humanize-duration` is in the `paths`.